# <app-layout> doesn't load (is empty) on ng serve --env=dev --aot but works with just ng serve (local)

Tags: angular5, aot

This is a quick question:

I'm performing an ng serve

```
--env=dev100 --aot (the dev100 is our remote server)
```

The element:

```
<app-layout></app-layout> **<--- LOOKS LIKE THIS upon completion. EMPTY!**
```

But, I don't get this issue with I simply do ng serve on my local box.

I've never seen this happen and there are no errors.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the wonkiness of angular 5's compiler, I had a dead component (something I wasn't using) and had the same signature, per se, as the one that was not being loaded.

EX:

```
<app-layout></app-layout> <-- NOT BEING LOADED
<app-layout-popover></app-layout-popover> <-- NOT BEING USED
```

My thought is that the compiler saw only the first part

After I removed the dead component, it compiled and everything's working.